# Write into existing xml file in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have xml file like following for displaying ads using asp:AdRotator in asp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Advertisements>
 <Ad>
<ImageUrl>~/xxx/xxx.jpg</ImageUrl>
<NavigateUrl>xxx</NavigateUrl>
<AlternateText>xxx</AlternateText>
<Impressions>100</Impressions>
 </Ad>
</Advertisements>
```

now i want to add new data between ...  tag in asp.net using vb how to do that..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little googling should help you. Anyways a quick reference for what you want to achieve - http://forums.asp.net/t/1223099.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145952/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072303-1.aspx

and

https://web.archive.org/web/20210417083045/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072303-1.2.aspx